# Finite Space that is Not Normal

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Is there any finite space that is not normal? By "normal", I refer to a space in which disjoint closed sets can be separated by disjoint open sets.

Comment: Not that it influences the answer, but it might be advisable to state which nomenclature you use, is a normal space a space that is $T_4$ and $T_1$, or is a $T_4$ space one that is normal and $T_1$? For other questions, that may be a crucial information.

Answer (score 6):

You can take $\{a,b,c\}$ with open sets $\emptyset$, $\{b,c\}$, $\{a,c\}$, $\{c\}$, $\{a,b,c\}$.

Then $\{a\}, \{b\}$ are disjoint closed sets. The open sets that contain them, $\{a,c\}$, $\{b,c\}$, $\{a,b,c\}$ are never disjoint.

Comment: T4 space is normal and T1.

Answer (score 1):

One of the other answers is a special case of the [finite particular point topology](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000007), which is defined as follows:

> Let $X$ be any finite set and fix a particular point $p$ of $X$. A set
> is open in this topology if it contains $p$ or is empty.

Now, any two nonempty open sets must intersect in at least the point $p$, so there are no nonempty, disjoint open sets. In particular, the space is not normal.